# XML parsing error on symbian s60

Tags: c++, symbian, carbide

I have a problem with Carbide C++.

I'm trying to use function from Nokia Forum to read xml files. So I found this article:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_parse_XML_file_using_CParser_class

And I've created a XmlHandle.h and XmlHandle.cpp files.

But I don't know how I can use this.

I try something like this:

```
_LIT( KConfigFile, "config.xml" );
(...)
CXmlHandler* iXmlHandler;
<br>iXmlHandler = CXmlHandler::NewL();
TFileName fileName;
fileName.Append( KConfigFile );
iXmlHandler->StartParsingWithAoL( fileName );
```

But when I try to compile project I am receiving this error:

```
No source available for "0x2539636( ekern.exe )() "
Thread myProject::myProject Panic ALLOC: 3bcb1558
```

Can someone tell me what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest making your code marked as code so it's easier to read on this question.

Answer (score 0):

ALLOC panic means you haven't freed some resources. I guess the StartParsingWithAoL leaves, and the iXmlHandler isn't deleted (either it's a member variable that isn't deleted in destructor, or it's local variable that you haven't put on the cleanup stack). It's hard to tell more without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get these errors during compilation. Did you get it actaully when running in emulator?
I don't see :

delete iXMLHandler;

Where exactly in your code does this error occure?